# How to see if a key has the same value across time

Tags: r

I'm trying to see if my users have ordered the same product for all their orders placed.

My dataset looks like this -

```
Users  Product Ordered  
A        Onion                
A        Onion                
A        Onion                
B        Carrots              
B        Carrots              
B        Spinach
```

And I want to create a new column called **ordered the same thing?**

```
Users  Product Ordered   Ordered the same thing?
A        Onion                Y
A        Onion                Y
A        Onion                Y
B        Carrots              N
B        Carrots              N
B        Spinach              N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can check this with `n_distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(Users) %>%
  mutate(OrderedtheSamething = n_distinct(ProductOrdered)==1)
```

It returns a logical column (which is more preferrable than a "Y/N").  But if we need it, change the `mutate` step to

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(Users) %>%
  mutate(OrderedtheSamething = c("N", "Y")[(n_distinct(ProductOrdered)==1) +1])
```

---

Similar options with `data.table` would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, OrderedtheSamething := uniqueN(ProductOrdered)==1, by = Users]
```

---

Or using `base R` with `table`

```
df1$OrderedtheSamething = df1$Users %in% names(which(rowSums(table(df1) > 
                        0) == 1))
```